# Express error handler inside router doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express

I've an express application with a global [error handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) like this:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

Now, I've refactored the app to have a dedicated [router](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) only for error handling and related views (the app show nice error message to users, hiding internal errors):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// add one or more routers that throw errors
var myRouter = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     next(new Error('Internal error'));
});
// more handlers...

// ...and finally the new errors router
var errRouter = express.Router();
errRouter.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  logError(err);
  renderNiceErrorView(err);
});

app.use(errRouter);
```

But now that this error handler is inside the router, it doesn't catch errors anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that express [looks for a four parameter function](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L65) when routing errors, but the *Router* function [has only three](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L46) (req, res, next) like a standard middleware.

So, a catch-all error handler should be declared directly on the app:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // TODO: handle the error
});
```

This is an [expected](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2633) 
and [known](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2679) behavior: you can find more information and other ways to structure your code at those links. Read them carefully.

If you want to know how to the express routing works, start your app with debug on and inspect flag:

```
DEBUG=express:* node --inspect index.js
```

Then open Chrome devtools, attach them to you process, add a breakpoint on the line that throws an error (or throw an error manually) and *play* with step-into, step-over buttons.